# Is there anything wrong with my foreach loop?

Tags: xml, powershell, foreach

I have this code that I am trying to run. Is there a way to validate that the content I am getting is `href` and write it on the screen?

```bsh
[System.Xml.XmlDocument] $xd = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$file = Resolve-Path("D:\Powershell\XML\iptree.xml")
$xd.Load($file)
$nodelist = $xd.SelectNodes("/name/@*") # XPath is case sensitive
foreach ($attr in $nodelist) {
  Write-Host "xml data " $attr
}
```

XML File

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<item id="Integrated Projects - XYZ">
<content><name><![CDATA[Integrated Projects - XYZ]]></name></content>
<item id="67e26e0e-32ad-432b-b054-7666301539ca">
<content><name href="https://inside.nov.com/ipeh/107377" target="_blank" ><![CDATA[377 - Train - ]]></name></content>
</item>
<item id="e9e91ec2-59c0-4122-b4f9-feb2aff6b2a6">
<content><name href="https://inside.nov.com/ipeh/107378" target="_blank" ><![CDATA[78 - Energy]]></name></content>
</item>
<item id="34043397-ec4b-480c-99c4-110f79e505bb">
<content><name href="https://inside.nov.com/ipeh/120025" target="_blank" ><![CDATA[25-Gam]]></name></content>
</item>
<item id="afe44549-b1ab-420c-b43a-fdd0ddbf7a7c">
<content><name href="https://inside.nov.com/ipeh/120026" target="_blank" ><![CDATA[26 - Pevamping]]></name></content>
</item>
</item>
</root>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to achieve. What do you mean by "validate that the content is `href`"? Do you want to validate that the (`<name>`?) nodes contain a `href` attribute? That the URL is valid? What output do you expect from your sample input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like below :

```
[System.Xml.XmlDocument] $xd = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$file = resolve-path("D:\Powershell\XML\iptree.xml")
$xd.load($file)
$nodelist = $xd.selectnodes("//name/@href") # XPath is case sensitive
foreach ($attr in $nodelist) 
{
  write-host "xml data " $attr.value

}
```

In order to get `href` attributes xpath should be `//name/@href` and use `$attr.value` to write to host.

Output for your xml :

```
xml data  https://inside.nov.com/ipeh/107377
xml data  https://inside.nov.com/ipeh/107378
xml data  https://inside.nov.com/ipeh/120025
xml data  https://inside.nov.com/ipeh/120026
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to print all links within the *href* tag, you could also grab those with a *regex*:

```
$content = Get-Content 'D:\Powershell\XML\iptree.xml' -raw
[regex]::Matches($content, 'href="([^"]+)') | ForEach-Object{ 
    $_.Groups[1].Value
}
```

**Output:**

```
https://inside.nov.com/ipeh/107377
https://inside.nov.com/ipeh/107378
https://inside.nov.com/ipeh/120025
https://inside.nov.com/ipeh/120026
```

Comment: Isn't regex overkill to get `href`s?

Comment: @svasa Depends on his needs. It is less code and doesn't require to xml parsing. So probably not.